# Не отображается страница сайта

Tags: apache, debian, apache2, config, vds

Всем хай!
Настроил апач[image: апач]

Создал файл index.php [image: index.php]

Запускаю апач и получаю:[image: Результат: белая страница]

Единственное на что я обратил внимание прежде чем переписывать и случайно всё поломать это вкладка network: [image: response network]
Она отдала респонс, но он почему-то серый и не выводится на страницу. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Интересно ещё то, что если я напишу echo "<h1> hi </h1>"; , то всё отлично выведется. Почему же он так работает?

Comment: Для начала смотри логи и  научись писать конструкции php безопасно. short_open_tag зло и потому отключено по дефолту. Вангую в этом и причина.

Answer (score 0):

@Владислав Гривенко, потомучто надо писать не в апострофах, а в кавычках.
Почитайте мануал: http://www.php.su/echo()

Comment: Дело в другом. У него просто файл не обрабатывается интерпретатором php. Поэтому ответ в виде скрипта, который браузер, естественно, не отображает.

Comment: Алексей, почитай мануал на сайте который ты скинул. Там используестся echo '...'; , но не во всех ситуациях

Comment: @xmikex, он же врубается AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
так?

Comment: Если да, то у меня прописано это в apache2.conf, но по прежнему команда echo не выводит на страницу результ(

Comment: Владислав Гривенко, а ты куда установил сам php интерпретатор? Может его в PATH нет или ещё что-то.

Answer (score 0):

Ты не включил обработку php файлов интерпретатором. Поставил бы настроенный XAMPP лучше, если нет желания разбираться в настройках сервера.

Comment: xmikex, я сейчас и занимаюсь настройкой сервера чтобы вывести сайт в прод) Желание есть разобраться, но я больше с нжинксом работаю, а тут апач :с